# Hadoop namenode can't get out of safemode

Tags: hadoop

All.

I use hadoop2.6.0.

When I force the hadoop leave the safe mode,using `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`, it shows `Safe mode is OFF`,but I still can't delete the file in the directory,the result show that:
`rm: Cannot delete /mei/app-20151013055617-0001-614d554c-cc04-4800-9be8-7d9b3fd3fcef. Name node is in safe mode.`

I try to solve this problem using the way listing in the Internet,it doesn't work...

I use the command 'hdfs dfsadmin -report',it shows:

```
    Safe mode is ON
    Configured Capacity: 52710469632 (49.09 GB)
    Present Capacity: 213811200 (203.91 MB)
    DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
    DFS Used: 213811200 (203.91 MB)
    DFS Used%: 100.00%
    Under replicated blocks: 39
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0

    -------------------------------------------------
    Live datanodes (1):

    Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (bdrhel6)
    Hostname: bdrhel6
    Decommission Status : Normal
    Configured Capacity: 52710469632 (49.09 GB)
    DFS Used: 213811200 (203.91 MB)
    Non DFS Used: 52496658432 (48.89 GB)
    DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
    DFS Used%: 0.41%
    DFS Remaining%: 0.00%
    Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
    Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
    Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
    Cache Used%: 100.00%
    Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
    Xceivers: 1
    Last contact: Wed Oct 14 03:30:33 EDT 2015
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Any help on this please.

Comment: It seems that datanode don't have enough memory to store anymore data. Free up the memory or add another datanode in your cluster.

Answer (score 5):

**`Safemode`** is an **`HDFS`** state in which the file system is mounted read-only; no replication is performed, nor can files be created or deleted. This is automatically entered as the **`NameNode`** starts, to allow all **`DataNodes`** time to check in with the NameNode and announce which blocks they hold, before the **`NameNode`** determines which blocks are under-replicated, etc. The **`NameNode`** waits until a specific percentage of the blocks are present and accounted-for; this is controlled in the configuration by the **`dfs.safemode.threshold.pct parameter`**. After this **`threshold`** is met, **`safemode`** is automatically exited, and HDFS allows normal operations.

```
1. Below command forces the NameNode to exit safemode

   hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

2. Run hdfs fsck -move or hdfs fsck -delete to move or delete corrupted files.
```

Based on the report, It seems that Resource are low on NN. Add or free up more resources then turn off **`safe mode`** manually. **`If you turn off safe mode before adding more resources or freeing up resource, the NameNode will immediately return to safe mode`**.

Reference:

1. [Hadoop Tutorial-YDN](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html)
2. [fsck](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#fsck)

Answer (score 5):

Running:

`hdfs dfsadmin -safemode forceExit`

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. It was occurring because there was no disk space for hadoop to run new commands to manipulate the files.
Since hadoop was in safemode, I could not even delete files inside hadoop.
I am using cloudera version of hadoop so I first deleted few files in cloudera file system. This freed up some space. Then I executed following command:

```
    [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave | hadoop fs -rm -r <file on hdfs to be deleted>
```

This worked for me!
HTH